# How to keep the active state of the selected menu item?

Tags: angular, hyperlink, menu

I have a menu and when I click on menu items, they become colored (to mark active state).

The problem is that when I send my link to another person and they open it, they don't see the menu item active.

How can I store the active menu state so that the active menu item displays properly for other people too?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJiKq.jpg
approximately:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener , Input   } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appZoom]',
})
export class BrowsertreeDirective {
  
 constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

   @HostListener('click') handleClick() {
      this.zoom('red');
   }

   private zoom(color: string) {
      this.elRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
   }
 }
```

Comment: What kind of menu? Are you using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)? Can you also attach a screenshot and maybe post some code too?

Comment: without MAterial

Comment: Then it's even more important that you post some code if you want to get help.

Comment: It looks like it is only happening if you click it. You could send the info about the selected items as query string parameters and read them inside ngOnInit for example. Then you can set the colored items based on that.